# Can mod analytics use the nice new UI used in /site-analytics?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, site-analytics

So site analytics is live, and it looks awesome!

[image]

It looks all the more awesome compared to the mod-dashboard analytics. Can the mod analytics page get some love and be updated to use the new design/layout?

Comment: What specific layout/UI differences are you actually talking about? The mod page has that pie diagram, too, as well as the plots. Some more images might help to convey what UI differences you actually mean.

Comment: @ChristianRau we don't get the big pie chart shown here on the mod version of the page.

Comment: Oh, so then it's only about that little thing. Meh, ok, thanks for the clarification, though.

Comment: @ChristianRau Not just that, that the styling is carried over too. The newer styling is *much* easier on the eyes.

Comment: Hmm, then you might want to clarify that in the question, as I still seem to have a hard time understanding what specific aspects you mean. But this might as well just be me.

Comment: What is this example from where Google is not in the top 5 referring sites? (Clearly I'm not a mod.)