# The site analytics traffic graph keeps cutting off words

Tags: bug, site-analytics

Some of the labeled slices in the Traffic pie charts get cut off. [Can mod analytics use the nice new UI used in /site-analytics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265944/can-mod-analytics-use-the-nice-new-ui-used-in-site-analytics) gives an example of this:

[image]

I've reproduced this behavior elsewhere. On a different graph on HSM (*not* the mod analytics):

[image]

Additionally, Nog Shine has an example on Hinduism that's fairly horrifying:

[image]

Comment: Typed the title to report the same bug and found yours. Your images look better. Mine are much worse. From [Hinduism.se]. You may add if you want. Here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSok6.png . Can't say which site is which without hovering. How do mobile web users or app users cope up with this?